# Escribir archivos en formato corto de 8 caracteres (python)

Tags: python

Estoy intentando escribir en un archivo .bdf coordenadas de nodos que tienen la siguiente estructura

```
GRID     35             -15.     0.     3.75
GRID     36             -15.     0.     5.
GRID*    37                             -5.             14.1421356201172
*       5.
GRID*    38                             -3.75           14.1421356201172
*       5.
```

Este tipo de archivos los lee NASTRAN con la siguiente estructura de 8 caracteres

```
$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678
```

**PREGUNTA**
¿Cómo puedo darle formato a mi array para que lo escriba en el archivo con esa estructura?

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, ¿has probado pyNastran: https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pynastran?

Comment: Le he estado echando un ojo pero soy bastante novato y no sé cómo obtener con la librería los nodos, modificarlos y reescribirlos en el archivo